# Using css mix-blend-mode with a child of a position fixed element

Tags: css

I would like to set the mix blend mode of an anchor inside of a `position:fixed` element but it is not applied.

If I apply the mix blend mode to the parent element it works or if I set the parent element to `position:absolute` it also works but neither of these are what I'm wanting to achieve.

Codepen with the three examples, I'd like #nav to look like #nav2 and #nav3 with the existing html.

http://codepen.io/wesdeboer/pen/QjawYv

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <a href="">fixed</a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav2">
    <a href="">absolute</a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav3">
    <a href="">parent</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body { background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200)}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}
#nav2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 100px;
}
#nav3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Tested in Chrome 45

Comment: I also couldn't get mix-blend-mode to work on children of fixed position elements. My workaround was to move the children up a level and make each child position fixed, but this wasn't ideal as required JS to position them.

Answer (score 29):

The reason `position: fixed;` on a parent element prevents `mix-blend-mode` from behaving as you expect is that `position: fixed;` [creates a new stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), isolating the child element from the rest of the document.

I verified that this is indeed the issue by [forking your example](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/VJwqEx?editors=1100) and creating a new nav item which creates a new stacking context in a different way: by positioning it absolutely and setting `z-index`. This new stacking context prevents the child element from blending with the background image outside the stacking context, just as we observed with the `position: fixed;` element.

[image: Demo Screenshot]

`position: fixed;` and `position: absolute; z-index: 3;` are just two of [many ways to create a new stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), all of which should create this issue:

> - Element with a [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) value `absolute` or `relative` and [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) value other than `auto`.
> - Element with a [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) value `fixed` or `sticky` (sticky for all mobile browsers, but not older desktop).
> - Element that is a child of a flex ([`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)) container, with [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) value other than `auto`.
> - Element that is a child of a grid ([`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)) container, with [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) value other than `auto`.
> - Element with a [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) value less than `1` (See [the specification for opacity](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparency)).
> - Element with a [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) value other than `normal`.
> - Element with any of the following properties with value other than `none`:
>
>   - [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
>   - [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)
>   - [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective)
>   - [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)
>   - [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) / [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) / [`mask-border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-border)
> - Element with a [`isolation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation) value `isolate`.
> - Element with a [`-webkit-overflow-scrolling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling) value `touch`.
> - Element with a [`will-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) value specifying any property that would create a stacking context on non-initial value (see [this post](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/)).
> - Element with a [`contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain) value of `layout`, or `paint`, or a composite value that includes either of them (i.e. `contain: strict`, `contain: content`).

Your options for getting around this limitation include:

- Finding a way to position / style the parent that doesn't result in a new stacking context.
- Applying the problematic styling / positioning to the children instead of the parent; ie, positioning the individual children using `fixed`.
- Applying `mix-blend-mode` to the parent that has created the new stacking context rather than a child of that stacking context.
- Applying the background image to the parent that has created the new stacking context and sizing / positioning it to align with the existing background image.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get around this when trying to achieve a "sticky header" effect is to use **position: sticky**, instad of position: fixed. Somehow this keeps the mix-blend-mode filter intact while still creating a new stacking context.

```
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}
```